# How to modify the code so it also matches html tags with attributes?

Tags: java, html

So this is the code I'm using to match HTML tags; it works when I use tags such as `<body> </body>` but not with `<table border = "3"> </table>`. How do I modify it so that it also works with attributes? Part of the code is below:

```
public class MatchDel {
    public static boolean isHTMLMatched(String html) {
        LinkedStack<String> buffer = new LinkedStack<>();
        int j = html.indexOf('<');
        while(j != -1) {
            int k = html.indexOf('>', j+1);
            if(k == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            String tag = html.substring(j+1, k);
            if(!tag.startsWith("/")) {
                buffer.push(tag);
            }
            else {
                if(buffer.isEmpty()) {
                    return false;
                }
                if(!tag.substring(1).equals(buffer.pop())) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            j = html.indexOf('<', k+1);
        }
        return buffer.isEmpty();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isHTMLMatched("<body> </body>"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would highly suggest you use an HTML parser, rather than trying to write your own.

Comment: instead of looking for index of > look for index of space and go from there

Comment: @DCR hi I tried playing with it and finding the index with the space but i still didn't get a correct answer. Could you please show me what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the document, for finding some elements and to get at the data inside those elements.

To get the value of an attribute, use the `Node.attr(String key)` method
For the text on an element (and its combined children), use `Element.text()`
For HTML, use `Element.html()`, or `Node.outerHtml()` as appropriate

For example:

```
    String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element link = doc.select("a").first();
    
    String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
    String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
    String linkText = link.text(); // "example""
    
    String linkOuterH = link.outerHtml(); 
        // "<a href="http://example.com"><b>example</b></a>"
    String linkInnerH = link.html(); // "<b>example</b>"
```

See [jsoup: Java HTML Parser](https://jsoup.org/)

---

## EDIT:

The problem in your code is in this line: `if(!tag.substring(1).equals(buffer.pop()))` , because you're comparing `table border = "3"` to the string `table`, you can solve this by taking only the first word `table` from the string `table border = "3"`, you can try this code:

```
public class d {
    public static boolean isHTMLMatched(String html) {
        Stack<String> buffer = new Stack<>();
        String st="";//ADDED BY ME
        String s="";//ADDED BY ME
        int j = html.indexOf('<');
        while(j != -1) {
            int k = html.indexOf('>', j+1);
            if(k == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            String tag = html.substring(j+1, k);
            if(!tag.startsWith("/")) {
                buffer.push(tag);
            }
            else {
                if(buffer.isEmpty()) {
                    return false;
                }         
                s=buffer.pop();//ADDED BY ME
                if(s.indexOf(" ")!=-1)//ADDED BY ME
                    st=s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" "));//ADDED BY ME
                else st=s;//ADDED BY ME
                if(!tag.substring(1).equals(st)) {//<----------------PROBLEM WAS HERE
                    return false;
                }
            }
            j = html.indexOf('<', k+1);
        }
        return buffer.isEmpty();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isHTMLMatched("<table border = \"3\"> </table>"));
    }
}
```